# C++ Why do values of the same variable differ?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have the classes `Sphere` and `Triangle` which are both subclasses of `Intersectable`. `Intersectable` has a public member variable `colour`. Consider the following code fragment:

```
float t_min = 100000.0f;
pair<float, f3Vector> point_hit;
Intersectable * object_hit;
Triangle triangle;
Sphere sphere_trans;
bool hit = false;

//loop through triangles
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->tvi.size(); i++){
    ...

    triangle = Triangle((fRGB)mesh->color[mesh->tci[i].c0], va.toVector3(), vb.toVector3(), vc.toVector3());
    point_hit = triangle.intersect(orig, dir, c_near, c_far);

    if(point_hit.first != 0.0f && point_hit.first < t_min){
        object_hit = &triangle;
        std::cout << "color1 " << object_hit->color << std::endl;
hit = true;
        ...
    }
}

// loop through spheres
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < spheres.size(); j++){
    ...

    sphere_trans = Sphere(sphere.color, center3, sphere.getRadius());
    point_hit = sphere_trans.intersect(orig, dir, c_near, c_far);

    if(point_hit.first != 0 && point_hit.first < t_min){
        object_hit = &sphere_trans;
        std::cout << "color1 " << object_hit->color << std::endl;
hit = true;
        ...
    }
}

if(hit){
    std::cout << "color2 " << object_hit->color << std::endl;
}
```

I'm expecting that at if I have an output of the sorts `color1 (1 0 0)` and the next output is a value with `color2 (...)` the outprinted colors should be the same. However, this does not happen. In fact, I always get the same output for `color2 (...)`. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This is assigning `object_hit` to a local(to the for loop) here `object_hit = &sphere_trans;` so using `object_hit` after it goes out of scope is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I've edited the code so that I don't create a local variable any more. But I still have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's slim that down a bit...

```
Intersectable * object_hit;
Sphere sphere_trans;

// loop through spheres
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < spheres.size(); j++)
{
    ...  
    sphere_trans = Sphere(sphere.color, center3, sphere.getRadius());

    if(some condition)
    {
        object_hit = &sphere_trans;
        ...    
    }
}
```

Now, when the condition is met, `object_hit` points at `sphere_trans`. But next time round the loop, `sphere_trans` is assigned a new object. So, of course, `object_hit` is also now pointing at the new object, which probably isn't what you wanted.

The best course could be to make `object_hit` be an object rather than a pointer. Or just hold the index into the array.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't let `object_hit` be an object (or at least I don't know how) because `Intersectable` is an abstract type. I didn't understand what you meant with "hold the index into the array"

Comment: Intersectable is polymorphic, but your `Triangle` and `Sphere` objects  don't actually exist in any permanent form. Your best bet might be to copy-construct them into object_hit : `object_hit = new Sphere(sphere_trans);` All the usual warnings about memory leaks and using smart pointers apply...

Comment: +1(Actually in two hour since I hit my voting cap) I need more sleep, I completely missed the second part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement:

```
object_hit = &sphere_trans;
```

you are assigning `object_hit` to the address of a local(to the for loop) variable. Once you leave the `for` loop this `pointer` is no longer valid and dereferencing the `pointer` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! So I've added the declaration `Triangle triangle` and `Sphere sphere_trans` to the statements before the for-loop. But I've still got the same behaviour ...

Comment: @StringerBell Can you create a small program the reproduces the behavior and maybe specify more specifically what the behavior you expect is. I won't be able to look at this again for a while but maybe someone else will be able to find other problems that may exist. Also in general if you are going to make updates to your question you should leave the original text as is and append any changes or updates at the end, otherwise new readers will be confused.

Comment: It may sound pretty lame, but unfortunately I can't do that in an efficient time manner. This method is just a small part in quite a large program and relies on data loaded from external files. Plus, most of the program was not written by me, so it would take hours for me to figure out how to create a functional derivative of the program. Sorry about that! Is there no other way for me to provide you with more information?